# redirecting stdout and stderr to same file in one statement (batch)

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to redirect stdout and stderr to the same file doing the following:

`dir c:\*.mp3 c:\*.mpa c:\*.asf c:\*.avi c:\*.flv c:\*.mov c:\*.mp4 c:\*.mpg c:\*.swf c:\*.vob c:\*.wmv /s/b > out.file.nlm.txt 2>&1`

This isn't working - I'm not getting the "File Not Found" error in the file - but when I break it up into multiple statements like:

```
dir c:\*.mp3 /s/b> out.file.nlm.txt 2>&1
dir c:\*.mpa /s/b >> out.file.nlm.txt 2>&1
dir c:\*.asf /s/b >> out.file.nlm.txt 2>&1
```

it works fine. How can I combine it into one statement?

Answer (score 1):

You are not capturing "File Not Found" with your original statement because it does not exist :-)

The DIR command lists the results of each file mask separately by default, but the "File Not Found" message only occurs if no file is found for any of the masks.

It is more intuitive if you apply the sort `/ON` option, and the multiple extensions become intermingled. It is then obvious that the final error state and error message applies to the cumulative result.

If you need a message indicating which extensions do not exist, then breaking it up into multiple DIR commands, as you have done, is the way to go. Andriy shows how to enclose the commands in parentheses so you only need to redirect once.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the `dir` commands into a bracketed block and apply the redirection to the entire block:

```
(
dir c:\*.mp3 /s/b
dir c:\*.mpa /s/b
dir c:\*.asf /s/b
) > out.file.nlm.txt 2>&1
```

In the command prompt, you can put the commands on the same line delimiting them with `&`s:

```
(dir c:\*.mp3 /s/b & dir c:\*.mpa /s/b & dir c:\*.asf /s/b) >out.file.nlm.txt 2>&1
```